# Reference model class in controller, so muliple data can be in one view

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get data from multiple SQL Server stored procedure to be accessible in 1 view so I can then run comparisons and create graphs/grids etc.

I got each section to work on their own, and I am now trying to get them to work together.

I have change my controller and put the field types into their own classes, and then created a "Ring of Rings" class, and put them all in.

```
namespace APP.Models
{
    public class SP_RESULTS
    {
        public type Type { get; set; }
        public status Status { get; set; }
        public condition Condition { get; set; }
        public rooms Rooms { get; set; }
    }

    public class type
    { 
        [Key]
        public decimal type_id { get; set; }
        public string type_code { get; set; }
        public string type_name { get; set; }
    }

    public class status 
    {
        //status
        public decimal status_id { get; set; }
        public string status_code { get; set; }
        public string status_name { get; set; }
        public string rentable { get; set; }
    }

    public class condition 
    {
        //condition
        public decimal condition_id { get; set; }
        public string condition_code { get; set; }
        public string condition_name { get; set; }
        public string rentable { get; set; }
        public int colour_code { get; set; }
        public int service_order { get; set; }
    }

    public class rooms  
    {
        //rooms
        public decimal room_id { get; set; }
        public string room_no { get; set; }
        public decimal type_id { get; set; }
        public int floor { get; set; }
        public decimal status_id { get; set; }
        public decimal condition_id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I then amended each section of my controller that was running SQL Server stored procedures, to use the correct class name instead of the "ring of rings" name, IE:

```
var outputmodel4 = new List<rooms>();
var command4 = db.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
command4.CommandText = "SELECT rooms.room_id , rooms.room_no , rooms.type_id , rooms.floor_no , rooms.status_id , rooms.condition_id FROM rooms";

using (var SPOutput4 = command4.ExecuteReader())
{
    foreach (var row in SPOutput4)
    {
        outputmodel4.Add(new rooms()
                {
                    room_id = (decimal)SPOutput4["room_id"],
                    room_no = (string)SPOutput4["room_no"],
                    type_id = (decimal)SPOutput4["type_id"],
                    floor_no = (int)SPOutput4["floor_no"],
                    status_id = (decimal)SPOutput4["status_id"],
                    condition_id = (decimal)SPOutput4["condition_id"],
                });
    }

    db.Database.Connection.Close();

    return View(outputmodel4);
}
...etc for other SQL stored procedures
```

..and the same with my view

```
@model IEnumerable<app.Models.SP_RESULTS >

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Rooms.room_id)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Rooms.room_no)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Rooms.room_id)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Rooms.room_no)
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
…etc for the other models
```

Everything looks fine in VBS (no red swiggles), but when I access the view in the browser, I get an error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[app.Models.rooms]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[app.Models.SP_RESULTS]'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[app.Models.rooms]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[app.Models.SP_RESULTS]'.

If I go back to my "rings of rings" model, and change it to this :

```
public class SP_RESULTS
{
    public IEnumerable<type> Type { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<status> Status { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<condition> Condition { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<rooms> Rooms { get; set; }
}
```

and change the following lines in in my controller:

```
var outputmodel4 = new List<rooms>();
outputmodel4.Add(new rooms()
```

to

```
var outputmodel4 = new List<SP_RESULTS>();
outputmodel4.Add(new SP_RESULTS()
```

VBS tells me that that

> SP_RESULTS does not contain a definition for room_id

I've tried prefixing the definition with the class name, with no luck.

I've looked on SO, fourms.asp.net and google.. can cannot see a solution (there probably is, but I am unsure what solution I an looking for.... if that makes sense).

Would someone be able to tell me what I need to do to get all my model classes working in the same view ?

I apologise now, as I realize that this question has probably been asked several (million) times, but I cannot seem to fine out that jumps out says THIS is that way to do it.

Comment: thank you @marc_s on the edit :-)

Comment: Are you writing **SQL** (structured query language) and really mean Microsoft **SQL Server** (the actual product) by this? If yes: please add `sql-server` tag to make this clear. If not: **what** database system is this for?

Comment: done. thank you again

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking for an answer (and for future me), I got this work by putting the models like this :

```
namespace APP.Models
{
    public class SP_RESULTS
    {
        public type Type { get; set; }
        public status Status { get; set; }
        public condition Condition { get; set; }
        public rooms Rooms { get; set; }

        public class type
    { 
        [Key]
        public decimal type_id { get; set; }
        public string type_code { get; set; }
        public string type_name { get; set; }
    } 

    public class status 
    {
        //status
        public decimal status_id { get; set; }
        public string status_code { get; set; }
        public string status_name { get; set; }
        public string rentable { get; set; }
    }

    public class condition 
    {
        //condition
        public decimal condition_id { get; set; }
        public string condition_code { get; set; }
        public string condition_name { get; set; }
        public string rentable { get; set; }
        public int colour_code { get; set; }
        public int service_order { get; set; }
    }

    public class rooms  
    {
        //rooms
        public decimal room_id { get; set; }
        public string room_no { get; set; }
        public decimal type_id { get; set; }
        public int floor { get; set; }
        public decimal status_id { get; set; }
        public decimal condition_id { get; set; }
    }

  }

}
```

Using VIEWDATA in the controller for each Store procedure:

```
        var outputmodel3 = new List<SP_RESULTS.conditions>();
        var command3 = db.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
        command3.CommandText = "dbo.pr_PROCEDUREONE";
        command3.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        using (var SPOutput3 = command3.ExecuteReader())
        {
            foreach (var row in SPOutput3)
            {
                outputmodel3.Add(new SP_RESULTS.conditions()
                {
                    condition_id = (decimal)SPOutput3["condition_id"],
                    condition_code = (string)SPOutput3["condition_code"],
                    condition_name = (string)SPOutput3["condition_name"],
                });
            }
            ViewData["CONDITIONSOutput"] = outputmodel3;
        }

        var outputmodel4 = new List<SP_RESULTS.rooms>();
        var command4 = db.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
        command4.CommandText = "SELECT rooms.room_id , etc FROM rooms";

        using (var SPOutput4 = command4.ExecuteReader())
        {
            foreach (var row in SPOutput4)
            {
                outputmodel4.Add(new SP_RESULTS.rooms()
                {
                    room_id = (decimal)SPOutput4["room_id"],
                    room_no = (string)SPOutput4["room_no"],
                });
            }
            ViewData["ROOMSOutput"] = outputmodel4;
            db.Database.Connection.Close();
            return View();
        }
```

..and then changing my view to read :-

```
table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
       Condition ID
    </th>
    <th>
        Condition code
    </th>
    <th>
        Condition name
    </th>
    <th>
        is it rentable?
    </th>
    <th>
        Condition color code
    </th>
    <th>
        Condition service order
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in ViewData["CONDITIONSOutput"] as IEnumerable<Happ.Models.SP_RESULTS.conditions>)
 {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @item.condition_id
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.condition_code
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.condition_name
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.rentable
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.colour_code
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.service_order
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
           Room ID
        </th>
        <th>
           Room No
        </th>
        <th>
           Rooms type_id
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in ViewData["ROOMSOutput"] as IEnumerable<APP.Models.SP_RESULTS.rooms>)
{
        <tr>
            <td>
                @item.room_id
            </td>
            <td>
                @item.room_no
            </td>
        </tr>
}

</table>
```